# Region [ a , b ; c , d ]

Tags: calculus

I have to integrate a function in this particular region. Unfortunately, I couldn't understand the meaning of the region. Could you please explain the region expressed as R = [ a , b ; c , d ].

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Answer (score 0):

Without more context, I believe that $[a, b; c, d]$ is the rectangle $[a, b] \times [c, d]$. That is, it is the set

$$ D = \{(x, y) | a \leq x \leq b, \ c \leq y \leq d\}.$$